# "He tied for <the> first place."

Tags: difference, definite-article, ordinals

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/tie):
**(1)** *He tied for first place*.
The first place is the only.  Then why is there not "*the*"?
I mean:
**(2)** *He tied for **the** first place*.
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: No difference, though in American English, one tends to omit the article.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - very commonly in British English too.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - in fact now I think about it, '_tied for/achieved/won/occupied (etc) first place_ with no definite article is the most usual way we express it in British English.

Comment: Nothing in your question appears on that britannica.com page. Why do you reference it?

Answer (score 1):

The example given in your link is (1) "*He tied for first/second place*".

This is just the idiomatic way of saying it.

(2) is awkward, though everybody would know what was meant by it.

Definite article ("*the*") would be appropriate when "first place" is used as an adjective (as opposed to a noun as in the original example) such as "*They both had their eyes on the first place medal*" or "*The first place spot was up for grabs*".